# How to share a version across all gems in a metagem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am building a Ruby library as a collection of related gems. All of the gems belong to one metagem. The structure looks like this:

```
mygem/
  lib/
  mygem-piece1/
    lib/
  mygem-piece2/
    lib/
```

I would like all of these gems to share one version. I could manually keep this in sync, but that would be tedious and error prone. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `mygem` is the meta gem, you will want to create `mygem/lib/mygem/version.rb`:

```rb
# mygem/lib/mygem/version.rb
module MyGem
  VERSION = '1.0.0'
end
```

Then, in each of your sub-folders for your composite gems, you will have a `gemspec`. For example:

```
# mygem/mygem-piece1/mygem-piece1.gemspec
require_relative '../../lib/mygem/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  # ...
  gem.version = MyGem::VERSION
end
```

(Note: this solution requires Ruby 1.9+).

Then, when you want to change the version, simply edit the single version file and release the new gems. Gemspecs are interpreted and then written out as YAML when you push to Rubygems, so the value will be "computed" at runtime.

Comment: Is there anything special I need to do to mark a gem as a meta gem? I'm thinking of the case when I submit this to rubygems.org

Comment: @Max yes and no. In your `Rakefile`, when you `require 'bundler/gem_tasks'`, you want to make sure you release the composite gems before you release the meta gem. Have a look at [how merb does this](https://github.com/merb/merb/blob/3110e9294107b4e1c87690d02e4c983b75b7c38c/Rakefile#L54-L59).

Comment: If you need help with that piece in particular, I would recommend opening another question though, since it's a much broader topic.